Integrar la AI de chatgpt con Alexa
soy un estudiante universitario de electricidad y tengo que hacer un artículo científico respecto a la integración de las IA de voz en la domótica, no sé mucho de programación, pero de alguna manera integré a gpt en alexa, este es el código, podrían ayudarme con el cambio de idioma, el código solo responde al habla inglesa y no tengo mucha idea de como cambiarle al habla española MX, por favor si pueden ayudarme con esto lo agradecería mucho
PYTHON
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractExceptionHandler
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractRequestHandler
from ask_sdk_core.skill_builder import SkillBuilder
from ask_sdk_core.handler_input import HandlerInput
from ask_sdk_model import Response
import ask_sdk_core.utils as ask_utils
import requests
import logging
import json

# Set your OpenAI API key
api_key = ""

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Skill Launch."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool

        return ask_utils.is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "Chat G.P.T. mode activated"

        session_attr = handler_input.attributes_manager.session_attributes
        session_attr["chat_history"] = []

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )

class GptQueryIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Gpt Query Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("GptQueryIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        query = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots["query"].value

        session_attr = handler_input.attributes_manager.session_attributes
        if "chat_history" not in session_attr:
            session_attr["chat_history"] = []
        response = generate_gpt_response(session_attr["chat_history"], query)
        session_attr["chat_history"].append((query, response))

        return (
                handler_input.response_builder
                    .speak(response)
                    .ask("Any other questions?")
                    .response
            )

class CatchAllExceptionHandler(AbstractExceptionHandler):
    """Generic error handling to capture any syntax or routing errors."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input, exception):
        # type: (HandlerInput, Exception) -> bool
        return True

    def handle(self, handler_input, exception):
        # type: (HandlerInput, Exception) -> Response
        logger.error(exception, exc_info=True)

        speak_output = "Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again."

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )

class CancelOrStopIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Single handler for Cancel and Stop Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return (ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.CancelIntent")(handler_input) or
                ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.StopIntent")(handler_input))

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "Leaving Chat G.P.T. mode"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .response
        )

def generate_gpt_response(chat_history, new_question):
    """Generates a GPT response to a new question"""
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"
    messages = [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant. Answer in 50 words or less."}]
    for question, answer in chat_history[-10:]:
        messages.append({"role": "user", "content": question})
        messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": answer})
    messages.append({"role": "user", "content": new_question})
    
    data = {
        "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0125",
        "messages": messages,
        "max_tokens": 300,
        "temperature": 0.5
    }
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
        response_data = response.json()
        if response.ok:
            return response_data['choices'][0]['message']['content']
        else:
            return f"Error {response.status_code}: {response_data['error']['message']}"
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error generating response: {str(e)}"

sb = SkillBuilder()

sb.add_request_handler(LaunchRequestHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(GptQueryIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(CancelOrStopIntentHandler())
sb.add_exception_handler(CatchAllExceptionHandler())

lambda_handler = sb.lambda_handler()
JSON
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "Chatgpt",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "GptQueryIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "query",
                            "type": "AMAZON.Person"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "{query}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                    "samples": []
                }
            ],
            "types": []
        }
    }
}

Intenté cambiar el idioma a través de las diferentes interacciones del alexa developer console, sin embargo no funcionócambio de idioma
También intenté cambiar el código JSON, sin embargo tampoco funcionó
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "chat gpt",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "GptQueryIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "query",
                            "type": "AMAZON.Person"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "{query}",
                        "Pregunta {query}",
                        "Dime {query}",
                        "Quiero saber {query}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                }
            ],
            "types": []
        }
    }
}


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!
